# What is DELF level of Assimil New French with Ease ?

Tags: vocabulaire

I’m learning with Assimil ‘a New French with Ease. If finished, what would be the rank as in DELF, roughly?

Below are the last lesson in the book, for reference.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Juste une remarque, depuis la réforme de 1990 il faut systématiquement un trait d'union entre les nombres. Le numéro de page s'écrit donc : *quatre-cent-soixante-et-un*, voir : http://www.orthographe-recommandee.info/regles1.htm

Comment: @Toto ok... just to be precise

Comment: I'd say around B1. B2 at best if you worked a little on your own aside from that, by speaking with natives, reading, or writing.

Comment: @Toto : l’orthographe rectifiée de 1990 n’a rien d’obligatoire, on a toujours la possibilité d’écrire en orthographe traditionnelle, ce qui est le cas ici.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_European_Framework_of_Reference_for_Languages) the attaining level is B2 of [CEFRL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_European_Framework_of_Reference_for_Languages) corresponding obviously to DELF B2. But IMHO a comprehensive method of learning French on your own (even a good own like Assimil's) could not replace the specific books for the preparation of DELF exams.